# Setting menu background image height

Tags: css

I've got a horizontal menu block in Drupal that has a repeated background image.
I'm now trying to make a drop-down menu for the menu's children.

The problem I'm having is that the background image repeats for the width of the entire menu and the height of the drop-down menu when the drop-down is active.

I understand why that is happening, but can't think of an elegant way to solve the problem. Using the background image on just the buttons should work, but then the background wouldn't extend to the edges.

Is there a way to restrict the height of the repeated image? If I can restrict the height, I can set it to the height of the parent menu. Any other suggestions welcome.

Comment: Can your provide specific code, and a working but simplified example of your problem on Jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Sure. Will do that now.

Comment: I've got a partially working example: http://jsfiddle.net/L46rT/26/
The primary item's obviously aren't supposed to move when the sub-menu is displayed. Floating them left fixes it, but removes the background image.

Comment: Here is a more functional example: http://jsfiddle.net/L46rT/39/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Don't worry about my method of hiding/showing the menu (or the cheesy background)

I added a class for the submenu, just to simplify the code.

The trick is to specify the `height` of the menu and then set `overflow` to visible.

working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/cockypup/Fs3WV/

This is the CSS

```
#blockmenu {
    background-image:url(http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS3LkgeI7h_C9w5PbHx_mIuVETgzO2NqJJdOSet-va1t6Q8nUAj);
    height:30px;
    overflow:visible;
}
#blockmenu ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
}

.sub {
   display: list-item;   
   list-style-type: none;
   padding-left: 0;
   display:none;
   position:absolute; 
   top:50px;
   width:60px; 
}
```

Comment: @Matt Coughlin: Thanks. Fixed. Funny that it worked anyways. I guess when you set `overflow` to gibberish the default is `visible`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute `background-size` to indicate the size of the background.

Check out this page for a full description of the attribute:
http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Comment: I tried using that, but that modifies the size of the tile rather than the size of the tile area.